# Create a VF page with several table reports

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting, reports-api

I've got a task to create a VF page with combined data from several reports. The data itself could be easily shown by several reports, but the requirement of the customer is that the data should be accessed from one page, to have at a glance view. And the second complexity is that the data amount could be huge - up to 5 mill. records. Also, user must have access to three filters - like data range, type of records etc. and the value in custom field.

I can't directly access the data from VF page since it allows only query up to 1 mill rows(with readOnly tag) and will take a very long time to proceed.

Right now I've decided to create a statistic object, manually(in trigger) control the data in the records of the object(on daily basis), and then on VF page load just retrieve the needed records and show them on page. It would be faster - since there will be something like 20 records per day(which is, assuming, i.e., that the user wants to look at the data for 10 years, is only 73000 recs - way less than 5 mill).

Maybe there's another way to somehow fullfil my customer's requirements? Am I miss something? Please, write down if you see any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're taking a generally sound/correct approach in using an intermediate object.

What I would do differently is to use either a batch class that's scheduled to run once per day or a queueable class that's chained to process those 20 new records/day asynchronously (the latter can even be fired by your triggers if you want near real time updates). Why? Because you likely don't need the data in real time.

You'll also probably need the code from the batch class (or something similar) to process all of the existing records. You may as well leverage that code at you continue to process new records as they're generated.

Comment: Thank you! I decided to implement both - batch and trigger(because, real-time data is really curcial - customer's direct requirement). Trigger will be used to update the statistic instantly, and batch will be fired daily/weekly to recalculate all the statistic in order to avoid different miscalculations(which most likely will be).

Comment: @EvAzi Glad you got it worked out. Your time requirements weren't entirely clear, thus the reason I stated my answer as I did. If this post led you to solving your issue, please help the rest of the community by marking it as having answered your question.